# Need to buy a genuine SONY PS3 controller. How do I avoid buying a knock-off?

Tags: ps3, controllers

I would like to purchase a NEW, genuine, SONY PS3 controller.

I would typically just head over to Amazon.com, click the model & color and then wait for delivery. After looking at the reviews, it seems that more than a few recent orders fulfilled by Amazon.com are actually Knock-Offs.

While I could see this happening with orders fulfilled by Amazon.com via 3rd party store fronts, it appears to be a problem with Amazon.com based orders also.

What options or alternatives do I have that my $50+ controller is genuine SONY?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Assile's answer and your note that the [PlayStation Store](http://us.playstation.com/ps3/accessories/) will direct you to other sites to purchase your equipment:

I recommend you choose Best Buy or Wal-Mart, as you can get the product shipped to the nearest store and go and inspect the product before purchasing, or for immediate return if you have already paid for it.

Comment: If you're going to go to Walmart or Best Buy, why would you order it online in the first place?  Just go there and buy one.

Comment: You can do it either way but the way I read the question was he was looking for a solution to purchase online.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to guarantee getting a genuine Sony controller is to hit up the nearest physical gaming store.  Best Buy, EB, Gamestop, or *insert name of store I inevitably missed*.  That allows you to examine and, in some cases, handle the controller before purchasing to ensure you are getting the real deal.

The clerks will also be able to help you out if you are unsure the controller you're looking it is genuine or not.

Comment: I wouldn't put too much stock in a shop assistant's 'help' regarding the quality of their merchandise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the playstation site provides an answer: http://us.playstation.com/ps3/accessories/
Buying through there may not be the cheapest, but must be one of most sure ways of buying a legit controller. I hope this helps you!

Comment: The Sony site just redirects you to one, or more, online retailers including Amazon.com. Good thought though!

Comment: I do apologise, I hadn't taken the time to check out what was behind the 'Buy Now' links. Sorry for the unhelpful answer! In that case I'd check out the reviews on every single one of the 3rd party stores :/